# When does the timer for 'OnBootSec' in a systemd timer unit actually start?

Tags: systemd-timer

"On Boot" is ambiguous to me.  Does it mean when booting starts, when booting finishes, mid boot, when timer.target is met?  The documentation that I've read doesn't resolve this ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnBootSec=` is relative to the boot time, as given by the kernel — basically, the time at which the kernel started execution. See [the relevant lines in `systemd`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/cb88da825460c410139a9a3041af849ee2d01d5b/src/core/timer.c#L439).

[The table of directives in `man systemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#OnActiveSec=) hints at this in its description of `OnStartupSec=`:

> For system timer units this is very similar to OnBootSec= as the system service manager is generally started very early at boot.

If systemd distinguishes its own startup time from the boot time, that indicates that the latter is the actual boot time (or as close as can be).